# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1813 Tablespace for table dbname.design_config_grid_flat exists

Tags: magento2, database

I'm getting the following error when I try to run the php bin/magent  command and I'm not sure how to fix it

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1813 Tablespace for table '`magento_e`.`design_config_grid_flat`'
ists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT., query was: CREATE TABLE     IF NOT EXISTS `design_
nfig_grid_flat` (
`entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
`store_website_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Store_website_id' ,
`store_group_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Store_group_id' ,
`store_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Store_id' ,
`theme_theme_id` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Theme_theme_id' ,
PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
INDEX `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_WEBSITE_ID` (`store_website_id`),
INDEX `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_GROUP_ID` (`store_group_id`),
INDEX `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
FULLTEXT `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_THEME_THEME_ID` (`theme_theme_id`)
) COMMENT='design_config_grid_flat' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914446/mysqldump-problems-with-restore-error-please-discard-the-tablespace-before-imp or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694168/error-tablespace-for-table-xxx-exists-please-discard-the-tablespace-before-imp

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151779/sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-db-design-config-grid