# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.design_config_grid_flat' doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, database, upgrade, magento-2.1.3

I just upgraded to Magento 2.1.3 and I'm getting the following error message when I go to the design configuration section:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'db.design_config_grid_flat' doesn't exist, query was: `` SELECT COUNT(*)
>   FROM `design_config_grid_flat` AS `main_table` WHERE
>   (`store_website_id` = '1') AND (`store_group_id` IS NULL) ``

**1st UPDATE:**

This is what happens after I run the indexer:reindex command

[image]

**2nd UPDATE:**

This is my list of tables in the database and you can see that there is no table to drop even though I get that error message from the reindex method
[image]

**3rd UPDATE:**

This is what I see when I try to run the create table sql command
[image]

Comment: Did you rerun console command `indexer:reindex`?

Comment: @MaxStsepantsevich I updated my post to show you what it does after I run that command

Comment: it is database issue, not magento, try search answer by mysql error during reindex. This table is dynamic flat, you can remove it and reindex - table will be created anew.

Comment: @MaxStsepantsevich This isn't just simply a database issue because it only happened after the upgrade to magento 2.1.3 and I see other magento questions with similar issues. I don't touch my database at all

Comment: @MaxStsepantsevich I updated my post to show the tables I have in the database and I can't remove it because it never shows up in the database, no matter how many times I run the reindex command

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914446/mysqldump-problems-with-restore-error-please-discard-the-tablespace-before-imp or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694168/error-tablespace-for-table-xxx-exists-please-discard-the-tablespace-before-imp

Comment: `[1] Export your current Database`
`[2] Delete Database`
`[3] Create New Database & Import DB from 1st Step `
`[4] Follow @St3phan Answer`

Comment: Any update @user3610374?

Comment: I'm getting the same error on my Magento 2.3
This is getting really annoying and happens to me a lot. www-data@579d4cdb05ab:~/html$ mag s:upgrade
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/var/www/html/generated/code/Composer
/var/www/html/generated/code/Dotdigitalgroup
/var/www/html/generated/code/MSP
/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento
/var/www/html/generated/code/Symfony
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento002.design_config_grid_flat' doesn't exist, query was: SHOW INDEXES FROM design_config_grid_flat WHERE `Non

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Table is missing. Run in sql console below sql query. After run sql query run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

```
CREATE TABLE `design_config_grid_flat` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `store_website_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store_website_id',
  `store_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store_group_id',
  `store_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store_id',
  `theme_theme_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Theme_theme_id',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_WEBSITE_ID` (`store_website_id`),
  KEY `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_GROUP_ID` (`store_group_id`),
  KEY `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_THEME_THEME_ID` (`theme_theme_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='design_config_grid_flat';
```

Comment: I was thinking that as well but the create table command doesn't work. I updated my post to show what I see when I try

Comment: Sounds like you have a design_config_grid_flat.ibd but no design_config_grid_flat.frm. Is missing design_config_grid_flat.frm file.

Comment: Somewhere you've imported the database, or database is after installation magento ?

Comment: I imported the database when I transferred the server but it worked after that and then I performed the upgrade to 2.1.3 and that is when it broke. If it is missing the design_config_grid_flat.frm file then where do I get that?

Comment: Do you have old DB ? before upgrade ?

Comment: Yes I guess so. It was an imported database copied from a different server and I ran magento 2.1.2 on the old server

Comment: import the old version of the database, check if the file "design_config_grid_flat.frm" there after import, if there is no need to do once the sql dump, make sure the "base unsecure url" is correct, run [setup:upgrade] ensures magento yourself that it works, check for file "design_config_grid_flat.frm" and run commands from the beginning

Comment: I can't import the old version because that will wipe out my data because I have added thousands of items to the inventory since the update

Comment: Import this for design_config_grid_flat.frm, when you finished what I say before, you copy file in new DB, but mysql you must off when you copy file

Comment: I tried this query but the table already exist and have some enteries.
Having same issue in M.2.4.1   imported products from m1 throught csv

Comment: anybody help please what should i do?

Comment: @IzharMehdi - if you have the table it means that your problem is not the same as the one in this post, read carefully, the error in the question.