# When i run Setup upgrade CLI i got SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: magento2.3, database, error, sql

Please give me the solution for this problem, I didn't change any modules i can't catch this error how it occured

> ```
> > SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> > 'amtdb.amt_tbl_price_list_data_from_sheet_marketing' doesn't exist,
> > query was: SHOW CREATE TABLE
> > amt_tbl_price_list_data_from_sheet_marketing
> ```

Comment: Do you install any new extension?

Comment: no didn't install any extenstions

Comment: Do you use any custom extension?

Comment: No there is no custom extension

Comment: I need to check your website. If you can provide it, you can add my skype duongquyet90 , I will check it for you.

Comment: Sorry i can't provide it because it is official thing

Comment: refer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151779/sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-db-design-config-grid