# i am getting this error when try this command [php bin/magento setup:upgrade]

Tags: magento2

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'magento2.catalog_product_index_eav_replica' doesn't exist in engine, query was: SHOW INDEXES FROM
catalog product index eav replica WHERE Non unique = 1

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions read and apply both and follow step by step carefully:

1.[Base table or view not found](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/3660)

2 [Missing table try this qury](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151779/sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-db-design-config-grid)

**NOTE: make sure your backup database**